# Call launchPurchaseFlow from Outside Main Activity?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, listener

according to the IabHelper docs,

"To start a purchase request from your app, call launchPurchaseFlow(Activity, String, int, OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener, String) on your IabHelper instance. **You must make this call from the main thread of your Activity.** "

I want to initiate launchPurchaseFlow from my SpecialActivity; in particular, I want to trigger the purchase when the user tries to turn on a certain feature by clicking a checkbox in SpecialActivity.

I can't just create a function in Main and call it from SpecialActivity (non-static method can't be reference from static contect), and I'm not sure how to easily create a listener and initiator between the two activities.

Is there some easy way to trigger mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow from SpecialActivity? If not, how might you implement a similar idea?

Thanks all!

Comment: I finally ended up just collapsing all activities but mainActivity and launching purchaseflow from there as prescribred based on specialActivity's return intent extras. I will have to reset the state of things after purchase as necessary, but this definitely seemed the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Take the context and cast it as Activity. So your code is something like this:

```
mBillingHelper.launchPurchaseFlow((Activity)mContext, sku_name, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```